# Why do i get <__main__.Node object at 0x04E2AA30> instead of the value for rotating linked list

Tags: python, data-structures, singly-linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, dataval=None):
        self.dataval = dataval
        self.nextval = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headval = None

    def __iter__(self):

        return self.headval

    def printList(self):
        printval = self.headval
        while printval is not None:
            print(printval.dataval)
            printval = printval.nextval

    def addBeginning(self, newdata):
        NewNode = Node(newdata)
        NewNode.nextval = self.headval
        self.headval = NewNode


def rotateRight(head, k):
    listLength = 1
    listTail = head.headval
    while listTail.nextval is not None:
        listTail = listTail.nextval
        listLength += 1

    offset = abs(k) % listLength

    newTailPos = listLength - offset if k > 0 else offset
    newTail = head.headval

    for i in range(1, newTailPos):
        newTail = newTail.nextval
        print(newTail)

    newHead = newTail.nextval
    newTail.nextval = None
    listTail.nextval = head.headval

    return newHead


llist = LinkedList()
llist.headval = Node(1)
e2 = Node(2)
e3 = Node(3)
e4 = Node(4)
e5 = Node(5)


llist.headval.nextval = e2
e2.nextval = e3
e3.nextval = e4
e4.nextval = e5

llist.addBeginning(0)


rotateRight(llist, 3)
```

I am suppose to create a function that will take a linked list and rotate it k positions to the right. I tried debugging the code but I keep getting `<__main__.Node object at 0x04E2AA30>` as a return value.

How can I convert that into the type of data I want like a string or an integer?

Suppose I have a function

```
def rotateRight(head, k):
    listTail = head 
    while listTail.next is not None:
        #do something
```

this code does not work but for some reason

```
listTail = head.headval
```

works because in my LinkedList class I defined the __ init __ function

```
self.headval = None
```

If someone can briefly explain or refer me to somewhere that explains this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried debugging the code but I keep getting <**main**.Node object at 0x04E2AA30> as a return value.
>
> How can I convert that into the type of data I want like a string or an integer?

You've defined your `Node` objects to have a `.dataval` to contain the node's data.

```
print(some_node, some_node.dataval)
```

would thus print

```
<__main__.Node object at 0xHEXYHEX> hello
```

for a node containing the value `'hello'`.

Comment: ah.. actually my code is still off by 1 index position. in the for loop the last iteration gives a value of 2 and after the for loop I assign a new variable newHead = newTail.nextVal which should give me 3 but it still remains 2

Comment: okay so actually in the for loop i took out the lower limit parameter for the range and it works.